# Committing changes on the website after deploying it in netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, github, netlify

I've build a static react website using create-react-app and deployed it in netlify using git and github. Turns out, I've to make a small change in my website now. What should I do so that the changes reflect on the already deployed site. I committed changes in github but the change is not showing in the live deployed url.

Comment: run `netlify deploy -p` again

Comment: nothing happened.my pushes are not being automatically deployed for some reason i can’t determine…

Comment: for git did you link it up and make it watch master? git is not a netlify tool, for auto-deployment, you would need set it up like shown in this tut https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/09/29/a-step-by-step-guide-deploying-on-netlify/

Comment: Thank u so much. I read somewhere that if we commit changes in github  it would auto deploy the changes to netlify.

Comment: Also that article doesn't tell how to make changes in the website when it's already deployed

Comment: yeah it should if you link it as shown inn the above tut, as you commit up to git (see answer below), if linked github will make a callback to netlify, and if you set it up it correctly it will do a git pull from your repo, build and deploy, you should see it hooked in on the repo in Settings -> Webhooks

Comment: my GITHUB repo shows the changes but but no deploy has been triggered on Netlify. Any suggestions on what to do further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can commit a new version of your website easily.
after editing or changing the file in you need to use

```
git add --all
```

and commit the file by the following command.

```
git commit -m"you can add you commit message here'
```

after these steps, you can add the remote by the following command.

```
 git remote add remote-name https://repo-link-here..
```

if you already added remote you can skip the step just top of this sentence.

after that, you can push the committed branch by the following command

```
git push remote-name branch
```

the default name of remote is `origin`
the default branch is `master`
you can also use the default names also.

Comment: I tried this method. the change is reflected on github but not on netlify.

Comment: instead of GitHub remote, you can change it to netlify remote refer this documentation- https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/repo-permissions-linking/#git-provider-permissions  If you have further doubt feel free to mention here

Comment: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/01/11/a-step-by-step-guide-assemble-on-netlify/